# FFmpeg w/ V4L2 for virtual webcam on Linux that crops, filters real uvc webcam

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video, webcam

Wondering if it would be possible to use ffmpeg w/ v4l2 support (on say Ubuntu Linux) to create a virtual webcam device, that presents a transformed version of real webcam's output. The idea would be that the virtual webcam device could then be used by popular video conferencing applications like Teams, Zoom, Google Talk etc.

The nature of transformations I am looking at is cropping on few of the edges, applying overlay text, applying chroma-keying, background replacement etc. I am looking for a mechanism that has least system overhead as well, which is why considering ffmpeg.

Comment: See [Is there any way ffmpeg send video to /dev/video0 on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/a/881341)

Comment: Thanks llogan. Perfectly answers the question. I found other Q&A on more advanced usage of ffmpeg itself. Since the answer is not on SU site system didn't allow me to mark it as a Duplicate and close it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible.

1. Get the `v4l2loopback` module

   ```
   apt-get install v4l2loopback-dkms
   ```
2. Load the module

   ```
   modprobe v4l2loopback exclusive_caps=1 card_label="Virtual Webcam" max_buffers=2
   ```
3. Run `ffmpeg(1)` reading *from* the actual/physical webcam and writing *to* the “virtual” webcam. For instance, I got some old webcam that only supports 640 pixels × 480 pixels @ 30.00 FPS (among other modes), but I like to have it cropped to a 16 : 10 aspect ratio:

   ```
   ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -pix_fmt yuyv422 -vf crop=h=400 -f v4l2 /dev/video1
   ```

   Pay attention to the order of parameters. E. g. here it was crucial to specify `‑pix_fmt` *before* (any) `‑vf`.
4. If you’ve changed the resolution:

   ```
   v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1 --set-fmt-video=width=640,height=400,pixelformat=yuyv422
   ```
5. Use the virtual camera from your application and celebrate.

I presume it wasn’t worth mentioning, but for the sake of completeness: `apt‑get(8)` and `modprobe(8)` need to be executed with `root` privileges, whereas `ffmpeg(1)` and `v4l2-ctl(1)` are run as a regular user *usually* (also) being a member of the `video` group. Confer the *group* ownership of `/dev/video*`.

PS: Some duplicate questions/answers are OK, especially if you can’t merge them because they are on different sites.